# SQL trigger not working when deleting a record

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

I have the following trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `delete_scores_trigger` AFTER DELETE ON `scores`
   FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE `users` 
   SET `darts_thrown` = ((SELECT `darts_thrown` 
                            FROM (SELECT * FROM users) as utable 
                           WHERE `id` = old.user_id) - old.darts_thrown) 
 WHERE `users`.`id` = old.user_id;
   END
```

The 'scores' table has two foreign keys as stated below:

```
ALTER TABLE `scores`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `scores_game_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`game_id`) 
    REFERENCES `games` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `scores_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) 
    REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
COMMIT;
```

I would like to update field 'darts_thrown' on 'users' after a SCORE is deleted. Because of the foreign keys, whenever a 'game' gets deleted, the corresponding 'scores' records will also be deleted. After or before that moment, the 'user'.'darts_thrown' should be updated with the trigger.

Comment: Why not use `delete cascade` to delete it automatically?

Comment: I changed the tag to MySQL, because the syntax is screaming MySQL.

Comment: @juergend excuse me if i'm wrong but, the 'scores' and 'users' table do not have a relation. How would you use `delete cascade` to update the 'users' table when a record from 'scores' is deleted?

Comment: It sounded like there is a relation. No, then you can't delete automatically without a relation. BTW you talk about a GAME table with does not appear in your code.

Comment: So I guess the question is does the on delete in scores fire before or after the trigger.

Comment: do you get a error?

Comment: `(SELECT * FROM users)` is redundant in your query.

Comment: @cdaiga whenever I do the same in phpMyAdmin, it shows me the error: You can't specify target table for update in FROM clause

Comment: @RaymondNijland I don't, but the field 'darts_thrown' is not updated.

Comment: @jordibenck OK I see, it's a workaround!

Comment: After you delete a score, does the User record still exist?

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html there is a note in Referential Actions section Cascaded foreign key actions do not activate triggers.